# Xamarin Forms Lifecycle

Tags: xamarin.forms

As App.cs is provided from Xamarin Forms I do bootstrap some of the stuff like AutoMapper there. However sometimes when the app is long in the background then the App's constructor fires again when going back from background.

This makes a bit exception since initial stuff being done twice or more.

Is that normal behaviour of XamarinForms lifecycle?

```
public App()
        {
            //Its called multiple times since app is running and going back from the background
            InitializeComponent();

            Bootstrap(new AppContainer(),
                      new TranslationBootstrap(),
                      new MapperBootstrap(),                          );

            Navigate();
        }
```

EDIT:
**This happens on Android**

MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle);
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
            RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            UserDialogs.Init(() => this);
            InteractiveAlerts.Init(() => this);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        private static async void TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs)
        {
            var newExc = new Exception("TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException", unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs.Exception);
            await LogUnhandledException(sender, newExc);
        }

        private static async void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs unhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        {
            var newExc = new Exception("CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException", unhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject as Exception);
            await LogUnhandledException(sender, newExc);
        }

        internal static async Task LogUnhandledException(object sender, Exception exception)
        {
            var logger = DependencyService.Get<ILogger>();
            await logger.LogAsync(sender, exception.Source, exception.Message, LogType.Fatal);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != Permission.Granted)
            {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this,
                    new[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 101);
            }
        }
```

Comment: does this happen in android or ios?

Comment: Ahh sorry didnt write - Android

Comment: Show me your mainactivity code please

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: So you are telling me that after sometime the App constructor hits again right?

Comment: unfortuneatly yes

Comment: And you are sure you are not initializing the app class somewhere else? I would suggest you to seach your files for app class initialization

Comment: I am one 100% this is only one usage. All I know that error occurs while AutoMapper throws exception with message: "Automapper is already initialized". And the only place I do initialize is new MapperBootstrap() in constructor of App.xaml.cs